# How do I get responses to an unanswered question?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, questions, bounty

I am new to the site, and am having some trouble getting questions answered. I wanted to know if there was any general advice for generating traffic for my questions.

I have read the responses to similar questions on meta, but none of them have been general enough. I also have seen a couple of references to "bounties", but I don't know what those are.

Anyone have general tips for getting answers? what are bounties and how do I use them?

I think that I haven't quite learned the correct balance between keeping a question simple and universally applicable, and providing enough information to be helpful. Specific tips and tricks about this would be greatly appreciated.

for reference, these are the questions I am currently having trouble getting answered:

[question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27297582/fixed-floating-elements-inside-table-cell-on-mobile)

[question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27320728/webkit-overflow-scrolling-breaks-absolute-positioning)

Comment: This question is *way* too broad.  (Ironically, this is also a partial answer to your question.)

Comment: See also: [How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046/262755)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bounties involve taking some of your reputation and offering it to answerers. You need 75 rep to do it, so it isn't an option for you yet. It *is* however a great way to get attention for your question.

Another way to get attention is by editing, just make sure your edits are *important*. Making a bunch of trivial edits for attention will be frowned upon.

As to your posts:

Your first question looked fine, though it might be so specific to your case that people don't know the answer offhand, and would have trouble setting up the environment to figure it out. Creating a MCVE can help with this.

The second question could use a bit more code, as we may not be able to reproduce it with the information given. Again, a MCVE would be *great* here.

Honestly, I think the biggest problem with your questions is that unless someone *knows* the answer, you haven't given enough code for someone to *figure out* the answer.

Since you are doing web development, I would strongly suggest containing the MCVE within a Stack Snippet so we can easily run it and see what is going on.

Comment: Thanks! What does MCVE stand for?

Comment: @kat Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more